# How can I restrict selecting to only rows which have common value?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Here is my table structure:

```
// users
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | Jack   |
| 2  | Peter  |
| 3  | John   |
| 4  | Barman |
| 5  | Ali    |
+----+--------+

// friends
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | friend_id |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | 3         |
| 1       | 4         |
| 1       | 5         |
| 3       | 1         |
| 3       | 2         |
| 3       | 4         |
| 5       | 2         |
+---------+-----------+

-- both user_id and friend_id columns refer to the id column of users table
```

And here is my query:

```
// $id = 1;
select distinct f1.user_id, f1.friend_id
from friend f1
where user_id = $id
      or 
      user_id in (select f2.friend_id
                  from friend f2
                  where user_id = $id);
/* output
| 1       | 3         |
| 1       | 4         |
| 1       | 5         |
| 3       | 2         |
| 3       | 4         |
| 5       | 2         |
```

As you see, my query selects

- `Jack` (because of `$id = 1`)
- All `Jack`'s friends
- All friends of `Jack`'s friends

---

Ok all fine. In reality, I'm trying to make a graph of the result. actually I did it. Now *I want to restrict the results to only **common friends***. I mean I want to remove **single nodes**. In other word, I want to select friends who have at least **two edges**.

Is doing that possible by changing the query or should I do that in the PHP layer?

---

A visual example and its expected output:

[image]

Comment: Add a select count condition in second `select ..` that should do the job.

Comment: Update your question and add the actul result form your select and the expected  result  .. (based on you data sample)

Comment: @scaisEdge expected output added.

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. You are looking for friends of friends, right? So why is 1 - 3 and 1 - 4 there?

Answer (score 0):

The bellow query will return all the common friends that are not direct friends:

```
select distinct f.user_id, f2.friend_id common_friend
from friends f
inner join friends f2
      on f.friend_id = f2.user_id
left join friends f3
      on f.user_id = f3.user_id
      and f2.friend_id = f3.friend_id
where f3.user_id is null
and f.user_id <> f2.friend_id
#and f.user_id = 1 Jack
```

The first 'inner' join returns the circle of friends and the second 'left' join joins the first-order friends from the circle -> the where f3.user_id is null removes the first-order friends. 
The last `f.user_id <> f2.friend_id` is to remove a user being a common friend to himself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT f1.user_id, f1.friend_id
FROM friend f1
WHERE (
   user_id = $id
   OR user_id IN (
      SELECT f2.friend_id
      FROM friend f2
      WHERE user_id = $id)) 
   AND (friend_id  IN (
      SELECT f3.friend_id
      FROM friend f3
      WHERE user_id = $id))
```